# velodyne position packets

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I don't know how accurate these are, but I tried to use position packets that described as below.

> Position Packets contain(source port : 8308): Header,
> Zero’s, 3x Boards with 8byte Gyro
> data, Zero’s, Timestamp, Zero’s, NMEA
> sentence, Zeros (total of 554 bytes,
> incl 512 data bytes)

I can monitor the packets using Wireshark, but I wonder if the packets can be acquired by velodyne ros package. I saw only 2368 port number(distance and intensity info) on source codes. I'm not quite sure that the velodyne package is implemented to get the position packets.

Is there anyone who knows about this? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61577/velodyne-position-packets/) by [Hyungi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4065/hyungi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-04-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some Velodyne devices provide GPS packets in addition to 3D LIDAR data.

The current ROS Velodyne package does *not* support those packets. I maintain that driver, but our HDL-64E has no GPS attached. With no way to test it, I am in no position to maintain that feature.

Others have expressed an interest in supporting it. I've looked at the specification. I believe it can and should be implemented as a separate driver handling only the port 8308 packets.

If you want to implement that, I would recommend starting with the [nmea_gps_driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nmea_gps_driver) maintained by Eric Perko, and adapting it to handle the Velodyne-specific UDP packets.

**EDIT**: there is now an experimental `gps_imu` [branch in the source repository](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/gps_imu). It's not yet ready to release, but user testing would be helpful. If you do try it, please post your results (both positive and negative) to [issue #24](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/24).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyungi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4065/hyungi/) on 2013-04-26**:
Thanks for your helpful advice.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
There is presently an [API review](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nmea_gps_driver/Reviews/2013-05-22_API_Review) for a new version of the nmea_gps_driver. The proposed changes should be very helpful for anyone implementing a GPS driver for the 32E. Please participate, if interested.